# WinSCP wildcard directory and file

Tags: winscp

I have directories test1-test10 in a remote FTP server.
Using WinSCP scripting, I want to retrieve every file under these directories.

This shows all directories:

```
ls test*
```

I want to retrieve all the files inside these directories:

```
get test*/*
```

However I get an error saying `no such file or directory`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround was a batch script:

```
set num=1,2,3
for %%i in (%num%) do ( WinSCp.com /command ^
                        "open <user>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>" ^
                        "get test%%i/* <destination>" ^
                        "exit")
```

This will create a new connection per directory, but it was the best I could do.

Answer (score 1):

Use `synchronize` not `get`.  The `get` command only downloads from the current directory.  Synchronize is recursive.

> [WinSCP Scripting Commands](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#commands)
>
> [get](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get) - Downloads file from remote directory to local directory
>
> [synchronize](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize) - Synchronizes remote directory with local one

Edit: Synchronize will get everything.  If it's likely that the directories will not change, I'd recommend putting the ten individual `get` commands into a script.

```
get test1/*
get test2/*
...
get test10/*
```

Comment: Synchronize is downloading everything including the directories test1-10. All I want are the files inside of the directories. My filemask is `/test*/*`.

Comment: I might have said I have test1-10, but this is my mock example. In reality I have around 500 of these directories. Manually typing each directory is not the most feasible solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
get test*
```

If there no other directories in the remote directory, you can even use:

```
get *
```